# Checking if the argument for a program is empty?

Tags: command-line, fortran

I run a program compiled from Fortran source:

```
  ./a.out N t
```

Here N and t define two positive integer numbers. Here is the code for this:

```
  character(len=10) :: arg
  call get_command_argument(1, arg)
  read(arg,'(I10)') N
  call get_command_argument(2, arg)
  read(arg,'(I10)') t
```

Next, I want to do following: if I don't enter neither N nor t (i.e., if arg,1 is empty), then the program proposes enter them through program (I don't know what is the analog of scanf in Fortran). How to do that explicitly, could You help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand it correctly, you are looking for something like

```
character(len=10) :: arg
call get_command_argument(1, arg)
if (trim(arg) == '') then
  write(*,*) 'Please enter N:'
  read(*,*) N
else
  read(arg,'(I10)') N
end if

call get_command_argument(2, arg)
if (trim(arg) == '') then
  write(*,*) 'Please enter t:'
  read(*,*) t
else
  read(arg,'(I10)') t
end if
```

Answer (score 4):

1) Your code (namely `get_command_argument`) is no way Fortran 77, but Fortran 2003.

2) Just use [`command_argument_count()`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/COMMAND_005fARGUMENT_005fCOUNT.html) to find out how many arguments you got.

```
if (command_argument_count()==0) then
  do whatever you need to do
```

Comment: But what about fortran 77? I don't believe in the fact that it is impossible to check if this argument is empty in the case of f77.

Comment: @JohnTaylor **Your** code is Fortran 2003 so there is no point asking for Fortran 77. In Fortran 77 you must use various non-standard extensions (like `getarg` and `iargc`), but there is no point to combine them with `get_command_argument()`

Comment: So, if the number of arguments is one, than I need to write
if (command_argument_count()==1)?

Comment: For your scenario you can actually stick to get_command_argument and check the returned value, if it is an empty string, fill the value with a default value, otherwise use the provided argument.